# R problem assigning multiple string values from a tibble to a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract multiple different string values from a single column and assign them to a new variable.
I tried the following:

```
variable = filter(tibble, column_name == "string1" & column_name == "string2" & column_name == "string3")
```

This fails. I have tried similar methods, but I cannot find a method that allows multiple strings to be held in the same container. I am using the tidyverse library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the `&`.  It should be `|` as no two elements can occur at the same time.

```
library(dplyr)
filter(tibble,column_name == "string1"| column_name =="string2"| column_name =="string3")
```

Or instead of `==`, use `%in%`

```
filter(tibble, column_name %in% c('string1', 'string2', 'string3'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much the second option you gave works perfectyl :)